Probability that each male sits opposite to a female in two opposite 4-seat rows

$4$ males and $4$ females are randomly directed to $8$ seats, arranged into $2$ opposite rows (each row has $4$ seats). What is the probability that each male sits opposite to a female?

The key is $\dfrac{16}{35},$ but mine is only half of that. I'm not sure what I got wrong.
There are $8!$ ways to arrange the group. Let $A$ and $B$ be the two rows. There are $8$ ways to select a person for the first seat in row $A$ and $4$ ways to select a person from the other sex for the opposite seat in row $B$. Similarly, we have the next pairs $(6; 3), (4; 2), (2; 1)$ to fill up the rest of the seats, so the probability is: $P = \dfrac{8.4.6.3.4.2.2.1}{8!} = \dfrac{8}{35}.$
What am I missing ?

Your answer is correct.

Here's another way to see that you're right.
After you fill the first seat, the probability that you're still alive after filling the seat across from it is $\frac 47$ because of the $7$ remaining people, $4$ are of the opposite sex from the first seat.  Similarly, assuming you're still alive, the probability of staying alive after filling the next pair of seats is $\frac 35$ and the conditional probability that you're still alive after filling the third pair of seats is $\frac 23$.
Multiplying these three probabilities gets you $\frac{8}{35}$.
